`notify-send` open program on click
I want to create a notification that opens a specific spreadsheet with libreoffice on click. The command libreoffice /blah/spreadsheet.ods opens the spreadsheet. I am trying notify-send Notification\ of\ whatever --action libreoffice\ /blah/spreadsheet.ods which creates the notification with the button but when I click nothing happens. How can I do this?
